# c# web service method that returns table row

Tags: c#, web-services, oracle

I'm trying to write a web-service method that takes two parameters

```
public <ReturnType> GetDictionary(string ID, string TableName)
```

and return a row from the table. 
In code I'm trying somthing like this:

```
oraConnection.Open();
string sql = "select * from :TableName where id = :ID ";
OracleCommand oraComand = new OracleCommand(sql,oraConnection);
OracleDataReader oraReader = oraComand.ExecuteReader();
```

Could someone help me find the right approach to this task?

Comment: Word of caution - passing TableName as a string in like that leaves you wide open to SQL injection. You need either to parse the string, or better, define an enum of possible table names and work with that.

Comment: Can i  check string to have only letters in it. if string contains something like ";" "," "." or " "(space) return null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not pass the DataRow down to the client, if really had to be like you describe, once you identify the DataRow to return you can return its ItemArray.

or even better, you create a business entity which contains all the fields you need and in the code above you initialize an instance of it from the content of your DataReader.

P.S. currently your code is not even getting a DataRow but a DataReader...

Comment: There are many tables in db with different structure and only client know what table he would request. So i cant create custom types for all tables.

Comment: I hear this answer all the times and frankly this mostly goes down to the developers not willing to model all their business entities... if you have 100 entities in your application, they still deserve to be modeled. Or you use an ORM approach which could simplify it a bit. Unless you are creating a generic application like a SQL browser or SQL Management studio... in that case the item array approach could work.

Comment: could you explain to me how to create an appropriate instance to return to client. Switch..case?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting a new WCF web service project, and taking a look at the example. It shows you pretty much how to accept parameters and return data.

Comment: Problem not to accept or return somthing.Problem is to select a table from db because table name is a parameter.